# Google Drive API v2 Insert Http-Post creating blank-untitled document

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-drive-api, http-post

Been banging my head against the wall with this for some time - was hoping I could find some help!

Currently messing around with the Google Drive API and doing a quick little Proof of Concept Ionic Hybrid Application.

The flow is as follows:

-User logs in to Google on device

-User takes a picture on device

-User uploads picture from device

The authentication to Google I have implemented works fine - with the auth token returned being stored to localStorage for 5 minutes before becoming expired.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", result.access_token);
```

The user takes a picture and then it is stored to the device and I then have the ImageURI saved to a scope variable for reference in the Upload function.

```
 $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

I have then have the following to handle upload to Google Drive:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization= "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");

$http.post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/?uploadType=media", {'title':'TestUpload.jpg', 'mimeType': 'image/jpeg', 'description':'Test Desc'})
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log('Upload successful');
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log('Upload failed');
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I'm slightly unfamiliar with the $http.post functionality and I'm not sure where to/how to format the params to allow me to attach the image file because it's currently just creating what seems to be a null file on Drive that has no description/information and no file attached to it. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated. As a side note - I am able to delete a file from Drive, so I'm 100% sure about authentication being handled properly - I'm unsure where to add the $scope.imgURI path to enable the attaching of the image file.

Cheers,

-Mike

Answer (score 0):

For uploading an image, you probably want to use chunked, resumable upload, as it's not the fastest operation in the world, and of course on mobile, not the most reliable.

You can have a look at the code in https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive/blob/d2954af867799f32fda02dcdf8f5db38442e1445/src/drive_s.ts arond line 389, or you could simply use that library.

I have a very similar angular1/ionic expenses app that takes photographs of receipts and uploads them to Drive, so it's very possible.